# Confusing difference between `count` and `size`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, collections

I have a `has_many :through` relationship between `Product` and `Order`:

So I create a new `@order` and assign it a product like so:

```
@order = Order.new(products: [my_product])
```

This manifest in the console like so:

```
>> @order.products
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Product id: 145, title: "Some Product" ...>]>
```

No for some reason I don't understand I get the following results:

```
>> @order.products.count
=> 0

>> @order.products.to_a.count
=> 1

>> @order.products.size
=> 1

>> @order.products.count
=> 0
```

I am going to use the `size` method now, since I want to know how many product I have. But I would have expected that `size` and `count` would return the same result for any type of collection.

Comment: To make it even more confusing, there's also `length`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this documentation out on `size` for Rails: [Rails ActiveRecord Size Documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/AssociationCollection/size)
Also the documentation for `count` is here as well: [Rails ActiveRecord Count Documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods/count)
There are Ruby AND ActiveRecord methods `length`, `size`, and `count` which are completely different from each other.


Your first example of:`>> @order.products.count` is attempting to call the Rails ActiveRecord `count` method (counting records in the DB) while your other example of `>> @order.products.to_a.count` is attempting to call the Ruby `count` method (counting items in the container within memory with no connection to the DB).


So to answer your question when using the `>> @order = Order.new(products: [my_product])` you are only creating the object in memory and not within the DB. You can read the documentation on `size` I posted a link to above to tell you why it is able to tell you either the length of the collection or the count of records in the DB depending on the context of its use.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

`size` is the in-memory size of the `products` collection.  You'll see when you run that method there is no sql query in the logs.  However, if you run `count`, you'll see it actually produces a sql query (try this in rails console) and since this order is not persisted, you're getting back 0.

Which one should you use?  Whichever you consider the source of truth based on where the lifecycle of the object is.